# Elementwise Sampling with map_fn Slow

Tags: numpy, matrix, tensorflow

Say that I want to sample a matrix with each entry sampled from a distribution defined by an entry in another matrix. I unroll my matrix and apply map_fn to each element. With a relatively small matrix (128 x 128), the following gives me several PoolAllocator warnings (GTX TITAN Black) and does not train in any reasonable amount of time.

```
def sample(x):
   samples = tf.map_fn(lambda z:
                      tf.random_normal([1], mean=z,
                                       stddev=tf.sqrt(z * (1 - z))),
                      tf.reshape(x, [-1]))    # apply to each element

   return tf.cond(is_training, lambda: tf.reshape(samples, shape=tf.shape(x)),
                  lambda: tf.tanh(x))
```

Is there a better way to apply an elementwise operation like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will run much faster if you can use Tensor-at-a-time operations instead of elementwise operations like tf.map_fn.

Here it looks like you want to sample from a normal distribution for each element, where the parameters of the distribution are different for each value in an input tensor. Try something like this:

```
def sample(x):
  samples = tf.random_normal(shape=[128, 128]) * tf.sqrt(x * (1 - x)) + x
```

tf.random_normal() generates a normal distribution with mean 0.0 and standard deviation 1.0 by default. You can use point-wise tensor operations to fix up the standard deviation (by multiplying) and the mean (by adding) for each element. In fact, if you look at how tf.random_normal() is implemented, that's precisely what it does internally.

(You would probably also do better using a Python conditional to distinguish training from test time.)

If you plan to do this sort of thing a lot, you might file a feature request on github asking to generalize tf.random_normal to accept Tensors with more general shapes for `mean` and `stddev`. I see no reason why that shouldn't be supported.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

See the `tensorflow.contrib.distributions` module, which has a `Normal` class with a `sample` method that does this for you.